# Amazon EC2 - Do two large instances running in parallel perform (more or less) the same as an extra large instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Do two large instances perform the same as an extra large instance?  I'm not too familiar with virtualization but just wanted to know from a high level if they are more or less the same.

- **Large Instance** 7.5 GB of memory, 4 EC2 Compute Units (2 virtual cores
  with 2 EC2 Compute Units each), 850 GB of local instance storage, 64-bit platform
- **Extra Large Instance** 15 GB of memory, 8 EC2 Compute      Units (4
  virtual cores with 2 EC2 Compute Units each), 1690 GB of       local
  instance storage, 64-bit platform

The RAM, # of virtual processors and storage is doubled for an extra large instance.  However the price is doubled too.  I was under the impression that Amazon would try to incentivize customers to get an extra large instance by making it's price less than two large instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some load is not going to scale out well or only with considerable amount of overhead. So a single, more powerful machine might make more sense than two smaller ones for certain scenarios. In general, some kind of overhead is always there when using more than a single instance:

- since you have more than one operating system instance running, the memory requirements for the kernel and necessary userspace code are multiplied
- the same logic applies for storage - the OS data needs to be stored multiple times
- interrupts (especially periodic ones like timers) need to be processed on all machines independently, using a multitude of CPU cycles compared to a single-instance scenario
- if servers are working on the same data set, cached data is likely to have duplicates among several systems

But then, a scale-out approach is often taken to increase availability. Obviously, all of the above still applies there, but is accepted as the necessary price for independently running system units.